# Installation procedure for Mapnik Node

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mapnik

After going through all documentation I keep getting errors while I use npm i mapnik

Error is here below. Even after installing python and verifying with python --version this error persists

```
C:\Docs\mapnik-my> npm install --build-from-source mapnik
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Docs\mapnik-my\node_modules\mapnik
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe \\node.exe" "C:\\Docs\\mapnik-my\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Docs\mapnik-my\node_modules\mapnik
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.18.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```